# Trying to Delete Duplicate Records from an Access Table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm looking to delete duplicate records from a table in my DB.  I am using the below Query to create a temp table in order to recognize the duplicates and then delete them.  However I keep getting "Could not delete from specified tables" error message.  Why doesn't this query work and how should I edit it to work?  Thank you!

```
DELETE [Carrier Name Crosswalk].*
FROM [Carrier Name Crosswalk]
INNER JOIN [Carrier Name Crosswalk] AS [Carrier Name Crosswalk_1]
    ON [Carrier Name Crosswalk].[DYCR TPA_CARRIER] = [Carrier Name Crosswalk_1].[DYCR TPA_CARRIER]
WHERE ((([Carrier Name Crosswalk_1].ID)>[Carrier Name Crosswalk].[ID]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below-

```
DELETE *
FROM [Carrier Name Crosswalk] AS C1
WHERE C1.[ID]<>
     (SELECT MAX(C2.[ID])
      FROM [Carrier Name Crosswalk] AS C2
      WHERE C2.[DYCR TPA_CARRIER] = C1.[DYCR TPA_CARRIER]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```
DELETE *
FROM [Carrier Name Crosswalk] t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Carrier Name Crosswalk] t2
              WHERE t1.[DYCR TPA_CARRIER] = t2.[DYCR TPA_CARRIER] AND
                    t2.ID < t1.ID) = TRUE;
```

The logic here is check, in an `EXISTS` clause, if, for every `DYCR TPA_CARRIER`, we can find in the same table another matching carrier whose `ID` value is *less* than the `ID` of the current record being considered for deletion.  If we *can* find such a lower `ID` record, then we delete the current record, which then must be a duplicate.